# Corollary to Hahn Banach

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X,Y$ be normed spaces and $x\neq 0\in X$, $y\in Y$. There exists a continuous linear operator $T:X\to Y$ with  $Tx=y$.

I don't see how this follows from Hahn Banach. It seems absurd that every linear operator would have $Tx\neq y$ but I haven't been able to find a contradiction. Hints appreciated

Comment: Take a suitable bounded linear operator $\phi$ and let $T(z)=\phi(z)y$

Comment: do you mean functional? $\phi(z)\cdot y$ makes no sense for vectors

Comment: Yes, of course, I mean a functional.

Comment: $1/\|x\|$ is not linear. You need to appeal to Hahn-Banach here

Comment: Let $\phi (kx)=k$ for each scalar $k$. By H-B, $\phi$ extends from the $1$-dimensional subspace containing $x$ to a bounded  linear functional on $X.$

Comment: oh ya well that makes sense

Comment: @DanielWainfleet : +1, but I think you mean $\phi(kx) = ky$ for each scalar $k$. [with $x,y$ the fixed given constants.]

Comment: @Michael. No. I am going according to the first comment of Wojowu,  where  $T(z)=\phi(z)y$.

Comment: Does anyone want to type the answer so I can accept or do I delete the question